# How to extract the RDF snippet out of an HTML page?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, rdf, trackback

I want to extract the RDF snippet of an web page. Since it can even be inside a HTML-comment I'm at a loss here. Can anybody point me into the right direction, what libraries or classes to use or something like that?

The goal is to have the trackback URL to be able to send trackbacks.

Comment: whatr is the format or your RDF ? RDFa ? Turtle ?

Comment: Pierre, I don't know, maybe you do, you can see the code here: http://www.sixapart.com/pronet/docs/trackback_spec

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use pingback instead of trackback and I recommend everybody to do the same.